# java printing pattern to a file using PrintWriter

Tags: java, file, design-patterns, printwriter

I am writing a JAVA program to print a Diamond pattern to a file. The pattern is correctly printed on the console but its getting printed properly to the file. Here is  the code:

```
            static void print_row(int cnt,PrintWriter output)
            {
                 while(cnt --> 0) 
                     System.out.print("* "); 
                     output.print("* "); // or for loop, I just think --> is cute
                     output.println();
                     System.out.println();
            }

            static void diamond(int maxrow, int row,PrintWriter output)
            {
                 if (row >= maxrow)
                 {
                     print_row(row,output);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     char[] chart = new char[maxrow-row];
                     Arrays.fill(chart,' ');
                     String t = new String(chart);

                     System.out.print(t);
                     output.print(t);
                     print_row(row,output);

                     diamond(maxrow, row+2,output);
                     char[] chard = new char[maxrow-row];
                     Arrays.fill(chard,' ');
                     String d = new String(chard);
                     output.print(d);
                     System.out.print(d);
                     print_row(row,output);
                 }
            }
```

the output is like this

```
                * 
              * 
            * 
          * 
        * 
          * 
            * 
              * 
                *
```

Comment: your question doesn't make sense to me... is it NOT printing properly in the file?

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop in `print_row` only loops over `System.out.println`. To get the same output on the terminal in the the `PrintWriter`, you should include it in the loop too:

```
static void print_row(int cnt, PrintWriter output)
{
    while(cnt --> 0) {
        System.out.print("* ");
        output.print("* "); // Here!
    }
    output.println();
    System.out.println();
}
```